# Policy Based Routing (not matching packets) - Virtual Template

Tags: cisco, routing, juniper, troubleshooting, pppoe

I have this configuration runnning :
[image]

*[Larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IL9GH.png)*

I tested the policy based routing int the lab using two linksys router acting as ppp clients of the Cisco 7206VXR and another linksys emulating the Juniper (forcing this router to send traffic always to the Cisco)

traceroutes showed the traffic between the two PPPoE clients passing through the Linksys acting as Juniper (X.X.X.1 in VLAN 10) as i wanted because this traffic must pass the traffic shaper.

The QinQ tunnel wasn't configured , I suppose it doesn't affect the the policy route performance...

So as it worked I put the Cisco in production but now the traceroutes in our PPPoE clients doesn't show the Juniper in the path when the destination is one subnet of the Cisco.

Note: A.B.C.D /23 and the networks in the picture have the first ip address A.B.C.1 in the Loopback interface as secondary, in a common PPPoE server configuration

Anyone can give me any idea about what could be the reason??

I thought about the local client - PPPoE server subnet 10.10.0.0/16 not included in the object-group but as it is in production i would like some help first...